# Poor next.js image component quality on Google Chrome

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I am developing website using next.js framework. I have some problems with Image component in Google Chrome. It loading with poor quality. But when you download that image from browser it has perfect quality. No problem with other browsers.

```
           <Image
              src={url}
              layout='responsive'
              quality={100}
              height={500}
              width={1250}
            />
```

I tried to clear cache, but not helps. Maybe chrome incorrectly tells browser's size. How can I fix image quality in chrome?

Comment: I don't know about the Chrome image quality issue (maybe reset the cache in case the image was previously load by the browser with a lowest quality) but I'm pretty sure you can replace ``src={`${url}`}`` by `src={url}`.

Comment: I tried to clear cache from Chrome, but not helps. About src, I remove some parameters from url, that is why it becomes like that

Comment: Does the issue only happen in Chrome browser? Or is it consistent across browsers?

Comment: Yes issue only happen in Google Chrome

Comment: where you able to figure out why is happening or how to solve it @Developer?

Answer (score 12):

You can add `unoptimized={true}` property, then it will be served as the original size. Here you can find more information about Nextjs Image features [Link](https://mediajams.dev/post/how-to-optimize-next.js-images).

You can also add `priority` property to your image, then it will serve an optimized image with no affected quality.

```
<Image
 src={`/images/sample.png`}
 height={500}
 width={500}
 objectFit="cover"
 layout="fill"
 alt="carousel"
 priority
/>
```

Comment: On Next 13.1.6, setting the unoptimized property true works. The priority property is only for preferential loading of the image, it doesn't remove the optimization. Opposite of this, using lazy loading helps with page load time.

Comment: unoptimized works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is not really satisfactory since it doesn't fix the issue since your site would still load big images that would reduce loading time (and pollute our environment).

The issue comes from the width property and chrome not being able to handle it well. Setting your width to the desired width would fix the issue in a more graceful way.

A site I worked on had external images up to 7.2mb, this got reduced to 30.6kb.

You could start specifying multiple widths per device in order to serve different formats to multiple devices.